# How can i get items from firebase query

Tags: angular

Greetings to all members.
When I try to get the items from this search it returns me undefined

```
 this.angulfirestore.collection('xxx', ref=>ref.where
    ('yyy', '==', 'zzz')).valueChanges().subscribe(
      data => this.event = data,
      err => console.log(err),
     );
```

How can I do foreach in this query

Answer (score 0):

Again guys, I come to post the solution of my problem. I got it this way

```
myArray  = []; //I declared this array
this.angulfirestore.collection('xxx', ref=>ref.where
 ('yyy', '==', 'zzz')).valueChanges().subscribe(
  (data)=>{
  data.forEach(items =>{
    this.myArray.push(items) //then I did the push, and then I was able to foreach this array and get each item
  });
```